# Doc-Start appearing when using xr package

Tags: beamer, ref, xr

I am trying to write up an article that uses the xr package (or maybe it needs to be zref) to reference labels in two different documents: an article and a beamer presentation.  The references from the other article work perfectly, it is the beamer references that show up as

Slide 1Doc-Start.

Where 1 is the frame number which I am trying to reference. Looking at the aux file produced by beamer the entry is

```
\newlabel{posvnorm}{{1}{1}{}{Doc-Start}{}}
```

If I manually delete Doc-Start from the aux file, the final output is what I desire. So if there is a way to write the label so "Doc-Start" isn't included, or suppressed when calling the label, I should be good to go.  A a heads up, there will be multiple references to difference beamer slides in the main article.

Code for the main article:

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{xr}
    \externaldocument{../Folder1/mwe_article}
    \externaldocument{../Folder2/mwe_beamer}
    \begin{document}
    Slide \ref{posvnorm}

    Article \ref{pos} and \ref{norm}
    \end{document}
```

Code for the beamer slides

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame} \label{posvnorm}
\frametitle{Title}
Words go here
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Code for the article being referenced

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}

\item Blah \label{pos}


\item Blarg \label{norm}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you mix documents which use `hyperref` (automatically loaded by beamer) with documents that don't use it. If you change the two article documents to include `hyperref`, the following works fine and even produces click-able like that will automatically open the linked documents:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\externaldocument{mwe_article}
\externaldocument{mwe_beamer}
\begin{document}
Slide \ref{posvnorm}

Article \ref{pos} and \ref{norm}
\end{document}
```

---

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}

\item Blah \label{pos}


\item Blarg \label{norm}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works great.

Comment: @RyanLee You're welcome!